# How to prevent Item to be added to DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

### My Problem

I am trying to prevent the user to add empty [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) rows when using the built-in .NET [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) AddNewItem-functionality. So when a user tries to commit an AddNew transaction of the [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) and leaves `PageItemViewModel.Text` empty, it should disappears from the [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx).

### The code

**`ViewModels`**

```
public class PageItemViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class PageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PageItemViewModel> PageItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PageItemViewModel>();
}
```

**`View`**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          CanUserAddRows="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PageItems}" />
```

### I already tried

... removing the automatically created object from the [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)'s [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) while handling:

- [`DataGrid.AddingNewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem.aspx)
- [`INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) of `PageViewModel.PageItems`
- [`IEditableCollectionView.CancelNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.cancelnew.aspx)
- [`DataGrid.OnItemsChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onitemschanged.aspx)

... but always receive exceptions like:

> - "**System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Removing' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction."
> - "**System.InvalidOperationException:** Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged event."
> - "**System.InvalidOperationException:** Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

### My question

How can I prevent the newly created `PageItemViewModel` from being added to the 
[`ObservableCollection<PageItemViewModel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/ms668604.aspx), when there is a given condition (in this case: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PageItemViewModel.Text) == true`.

---

#### EDIT:

[@picnic8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5915286/picnic8): The `AddingNewItem` event does not provide any form of `RoutedEventArgs` and therefore no `Handled` property. Instead, it is [`AddingNewItemEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.addingnewitemeventargs.aspx). Your code is invalid.

```
private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (PageItemViewModel)e.NewItem;
    bool cancelAddingNewItem = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Text) == true;
    // ??? How can i actually stop it from here?
}
```

Comment: You can override `OnItemsChanged` .

Comment: @MitraM - Modifying the collection in an overwritten OnItemsChanged method also results in an `System.InvalidOperationException:  'Removing' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.`

Comment: @Maverik - Creating the view models works flawlessly without problems.

Comment: @Maverik - I See... But I want the functionality of the wpf datagrid to have the empty line to create new items. I don't want to have a button I need to click to add new Items.

Comment: Removed earlier comments - realised this is a validation issue and not a general prevention question.. a crucial detail that I missed out. Apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't prevent adding to the underlying collection because when the end user starts typing in the new row, `DataGrid` will create and add a new `PageItemViewModel` object which at that time is initialized with default values.

What you can do though is to prevent *committing* that object by handling the [`DataGrid.RowEditEnding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending?view=netframework-4.7.1) event when [`DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs.EditAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridroweditendingeventargs.editaction?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Controls_DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs_EditAction) is [`DataGridEditAction.Commit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrideditaction?view=netframework-4.7.1) and use [`DataGrid.CancelEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canceledit?view=netframework-4.7.1) method to effectively remove the new object (or restore the existing object state) when the validation failed.

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var bindingGroup = e.Row.BindingGroup;
        if (bindingGroup != null && bindingGroup.CommitEdit())
        {
            var item = (PageItemViewModel)e.Row.Item;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Text))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                ((DataGrid)sender).CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An important detail is that the `RowEditEnding` event is fired *before* pushing the current editor value to the data source, so you need to do that by hand before performing the validation. I've used [`BindingGroup.CommitEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.commitedit?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.CommitEdit);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1) method for that.

Comment: It works without any problem. Thank you very much sir. I will reward you with the bounty as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

In your VM, subscribe to the AddingNewItem event and check your condition there. You can stop the action if the condition fails.

```
var datagrid.AddingNewItem += HandleOnAddingNewItem;

public void HandleOnAddingNewItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myConditionIsTrue)
    {
        e.Handled = true; // This will stop the bubbling/tunneling of the event
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: @Picni8 The `AddingNewItem` event does not provide any form of `RoutedEventArgs` and therefore no `Handled` property. Instead, it is [`AddingNewItemEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.addingnewitemeventargs.aspx). Your code is invalid.